# Django displaying the value of changed field

Tags: python, html, django, database, sqlite

I am building my first Django website as a post office that can track items in a database.
However, I am having problem displaying the location history of a tracked package.

I tried using simple history but it does not look at a value of a field while fieldtracker only works on my local shell environment. Every time I restart my shell, the history is gone and it does not work on the whole database itself.

My package model

```
class Packages(models.Model):
    package_ID = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    package_description = models.CharField(max_length=100,default="None")
    weight = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5,decimal_places=2)
    signature = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    delivery_status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    order_date = models.DateField('Date Sent')
    sent_by = models.ForeignKey(Sender,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sent_to = models.ForeignKey(reciever,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tracker = FieldTracker()

    def __str(self):
        return self.package_ID
```

My package_history model

```
class package_history(models.Model):
    package_ID = models.ForeignKey(Packages,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    current_location = models.ForeignKey(branches,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str(self):
        return self.package
```

Please if anyone have any idea on how to tackle this it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is almost complete let me just help you out a bit with the that:

```
class location_mark(models.Model):
   package = models.ForeignKey(Packages,on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
                               related_name='locations')
   current_location = models.ForeignKey(SomeLocationModel, on.delete=models.CASCADE)
   creation_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, editable=False)

   def __str__(self):
      return self.package.package_ID
```

after you create some location_marks for package you simply can get the whole "history" by accessing the relation like this:

```
package_instance.locations.all().order_by('creation_date')
```

it will return ordered queryset of all the recorded locations of particular package. If you need you can define it as a function like

```
def get_package_history(p_ID):
   package = Packages.objects.get(package_ID=p_ID)
   return package.locations.all().order_by('creation_date')
```

hope it helps